# Specify bound for any type that can be casted to integer

Tags: rust

I have a generic function that should accept both `char` and any other integer. Internally this value should be casted to a `u64`:

```rust
macro_rules! char_cast {
    ($ch:expr, char) => {
        $ch as u32
    };
    ($ch:expr, $tp:ty) => {
        $ch
    };
}

fn test<CharT>(key: CharT) -> u64
where
    CharT: ...,
{
    let key: u64 = char_cast!(key, CharT).into();
    key
}
```

For integers this should check whether `Into<u64>` is fulfilled. However this doesn't work for `char`, since it has to first be converted to `u32` and then to `u64`.

How could I specify the bounds for this function to accept both `char` and any other integer convertible to `u64`?
Or even better take any type that can be converted to integer, cast it to the largest integer type it can be casted to and then cast this one to `u64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no cast trait bounds even in nightly standard library.
However, you can use [`num::traits::AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.1/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html) instead.

Comment: thinking about my problem a bit more this does not seem sufficient, since I oversimplified it a bit. In my real implementation I want to accept both types that can be cast to u64 or i64 without data loss and then call a specific function depending on whether the type can always be case to u64, or always be case to i64. In C++ this would be rather simple, but in rust I couldn't find a real way. The closest would be to use a macro on the lowest level and just ignore the difference in the layers above.